# How to set the two types of authentication for airflow: AUTH_LDAP and AUTH_DB? If airflow can't find an user in AUTH_LDAP it has to search in AUTH_DB

Tags: python, airflow

I would like to set up two types of authentification in the Airflow webserver. The first preferred type is LDAP. If airflow doesn't find a user in LDAP it has to try to find credentials for the user in airflow_db (default authentification method for airflow).

- First I try to set several auth methods in **webserver_config.py**:

```
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_LDAP
from airflow.www.fab_security.manager import AUTH_DB

AUTH_TYPE = [AUTH_LDAP, AUTH_DB]
```

But It didn't work.

- After I tried to change **auth_backend** in **airflow.cfg**

```
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.ldap_auth.LDAPAuthBackend,airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth.PasswordUser
```

But it didn't work too.

Are there any methods for setting several types of authentification in the airflow webserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. You can only configure a single authentication type.

Airflow leverages [Flask-AppBuilder](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder) for authentication. Two notes:

1. OAuth authentication does allow for configuring multiple OAuth providers (e.g. Google and Okta), see https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#authentication-oauth.
2. A similar question was asked here: [How to support both OAuth and Basic Auth in FlaskAppBuilder in Superset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62617613/how-to-support-both-oauth-and-basic-auth-in-flaskappbuilder-in-superset). You could technically subclass FAB's SecurityManager to implement your own behavior.

Also, see this GitHub issue requesting the same: https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/issues/1803.